# Rails query for parent based on child attribute (if child exists, and looking across all children)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

`Order has_many TypeLogistic` but importantly... an `Order` doesn't HAVE to have a `TypeLogistic`. Both `Order` & `TypeLogistic` have a `status_id` attribute. I want to find all uniq `Order` records where:

- the `order.status_id = 4`, if this primary condition is not met, disregard anything about children
- and IF the `order` does have child `type_logistics`, then all child `type_logistics` have to have either `status_id` of 1, or 2 (not any other number and not `null`)

In other words... these are the records that WOULD be found

```
Order
  status_id = 4
  TypeLogistics
    1 - status_id = 1

Order
  status_id = 4
  TypeLogistics
    1 - status_id = 2

Order
  status_id = 4
  TypeLogistics
    1 - status_id = 1
    2 - status_id = 2

Order
  status_id = 4
```

These are the records that would NOT be found

```
# because order.status_id != 4
Order
  status_id = 1
  TypeLogistics
    1 - status_id = 1

# because type_logistic child does not have a status_id that's 1 or 2
Order
  status_id = 4
  TypeLogistics
    1 - status_id = nil

# because type_logistic child does not have a status_id that's 1 or 2
Order
  status_id = 4
  TypeLogistics
    1 - status_id = 3

# because not all type_logistic children have a status_id that's 1 or 2
Order
  status_id = 4
  TypeLogistics
    1 - status_id = 1
    2 - status_id = nil

# because not all type_logistic children have a status_id that's 1 or 2
Order
  status_id = 4
  TypeLogistics
    1 - status_id = 2
    2 - status_id = 3
```

I've written a piece of code that works, but it's clunky because it uses `select` rather than pure `where` queries. Help me out?

WORKING, SUB-PAR CODE

```
@orders = Order.includes(:type_logistics).where(status_id:4).select { |o| ([[1],[2],[1,2]].include? o.type_logistics.pluck(:status_id).uniq) || o.type_logistics.count == 0 }.uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `joins` would allow you to query joined associations. `preload` will eager load the type_logistics if any are present satisfying condition specified in `where("type_logistics.status_id IN ( ? )", [1,2])` query. `preload` behaves similar to `includes` mostly.

```
@orders = Order.joins(:type_logistics).preload(:type_logistics).where("orders.status_id = ?", 4).where("type_logistics.status_id IN ( ? )", [1,2]).uniq
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. if an order has 2 type logistics, one of which has status 1 or 2 (but the other has status nil or something else), it is found

Comment: oh yes, then statuses other than 1 or 2 must not be loaded explicitly. which can be specified by adding `where.not("type_logistics.status_id IN ( ? )", [nil, 3, 4])`, might work?

Comment: but the problem is that requires me to explicitly state which status_ids should not count, but i couldn't tell you now all the various numbers that are possible...